# Автоответчик в Contact Form 7 должен срабатывать по чекбоксу в форме

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, contact-form7

Суть такова. Изначально в CF7 есть возможность отправлять автоответ юзеру. Но нужно сделать так, чтобы этот автоответ работал только если человек в самой контактной форме отметил нужный чекбокс. Как это реализовать? Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо использовать фильтр Contact Form 7. Добавьте этот код в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_additional_mail', 'filter_additional_mail', 10, 2);
function filter_additional_mail($additional_mail, $contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance(); // получаем отправляемые данные
    $usercopy = $submission->get_posted_data('usercopy')[0]; // получаем значение чекбокса usercopy
    // проверяем значение
    if (!$usercopy) {
        // запретим отправку почты пользователю
        $additional_mail = array();
    }
    return $additional_mail;
}
```

Форма для теста:

```
<label> Ваше имя (обязательно)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Ваш e-mail (обязательно)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Тема
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Сообщение
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[checkbox usercopy label_first "Отправить мне копию"]

[submit "Отправить"]
```

Попробовать можно [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so648370/).

Comment: Вроде то, что нужно, куда это нужно добавить?В function.php моей темы?

Comment: да, забыл написать в ответе. именно туда

Comment: Спасибо большое =)

Comment: Протестил, всё работает как надо. Спасибо за хелпу =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь )

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте обработчик JS по событию клика на кнопке submit. Если чекбокс выбран - показывайте автоответ.

Comment: Мне автоответчиком нужно отправлять письмо, а не выводить на экране какой-то месседж

Comment: И js не подойдёт, насколько я знаю, отправлять письмо можно только через сервер. Тут вопрос требует знания WordPress, PHP, и в частности плагина Contact Form 7